# In need of a simple exponential lower bound for the Fibonacci reccurence

Tags: inequality, fibonacci-numbers

$f(1) = f(2) = 1$ and
$f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)$

I was thinking of this but I am not sure if it's correct:

$f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2) = f(n-2)+f(n-3) + f(n-2)$

since the base case is 1, then $f(n-3) \geq 1$ so we have that

$f(n) \geq 2f(n-2)$

applying the same logic for $f(n-2)$ we get the following:

$f(n) \geq 2f(n-2) \geq 4f(n-4) \geq ... \geq 2^{k}f(n-2k)$

when do we stop? When $n-2k = 1$ or $n-2k = 2$, so we have:

$f(n) \geq 2^{\frac{n-2}{2}}$

but I feel that I am missing something... at least I can see this holding asymptotically, but I am not sure for what $n$ is the last inequality correct?

Comment: No exponential lower bound may hold for any $n\geq 0$, since $f(0)=0$. On the other hand $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{8}{5}\right)^n\leq F_n \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{13}{8}\right)^n $$ holds for any $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. You can also justify that inequality by induction. First of all, $f(1)=1\geqslant2^{-\frac12}$ and $f(2)=1\geqslant2^0$. On the other hand.\begin{align}f(n+1)&=f(n)+f(n-1)\\&\geqslant2^{\frac{n-2}2}+2^{\frac{n-3}2}\\&=2^\frac12\times2^{\frac{n-3}2}+2^{\frac{n-3}2}\\&\geqslant2^\frac12\times2^{\frac{n-3}2}+2^\frac12\times2^{\frac{n-3}2}\\&=2\times2^\frac12\times2^{\frac{n-3}2}\\&=2^\frac n2\\&\geqslant2^\frac{n-1}2.\end{align}